# How to handle an event that produces changes in multiple state domains?

Tags: flux, redux

I am developing a map application. It consists of two components:

- a component that displays the current user location; and
- address search component with address suggestions.

These components rely on the following state domains:

```
state.userAddress = {
    name: 'Didzioji g. 10, Vilnius'
};

state.addressSearch = {
    state: 'inactive',
    query: '',
    addresses: []
};
```

When user selects an address from address suggestion list it invokes an event handler `onSelectAddress`. `onSelectAddress` needs to trigger two state changes:

- set `userLocation` to new location; and
- inform the location selection prompt to close

What is the correct way to design this?

- Should the smart component dispatch two actions one after another, one that invokes `USER_LOCATION_CHANGE` change and another to invoke `ADDRESS_SEARCH_HIDE`; or
- Should the smart component dispatch a single action (e.g. `USER_CHANGE_LOCATION`) which is handled by two different reducers?

Answer (score 3):

In similar situation I choose to dispatch another action from target action.

Trying to show this in code

```
module.exports.locationChange = function clickElement(element) {
    return function(dispatch, getState) {
        dispatch({
            type: actionTypes.USER_CHANGE_LOCATION
        });

        dispatch({
            type: actionTypes.ADDRESS_SEARCH_HIDE
        });
   }};
```

I use redux-thunk for async action.

Comment: This is what we officially suggest, yes.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more why this is the better approach?